# Series that converge to every real number via permutation

Tags: permutations

This great answer at MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/a/29488/8784, shows that the set of permutations of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable. However, I did not grasp the fact that he uses: *any conditionally convergent series [and that such exists] can be rearranged to converge to any given real number $x$ proves that there is an injection $P$ from the reals to the permutations of $\mathbb N$*

> How did he arrive at this fact? Is there a known proof?

Comment: This generally goes by [The Riemann Rearrangement Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/RiemannRearrangementTheorem.shtml)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: Are you asking why any conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to converge to any real number, or why this fact shows there is an injection from $\Bbb R$ into the permutations of $\Bbb N$? (I ask because the first seems more likely, but the second is the question you actually asked...)

Comment: Given the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem, the desired claim is clear, no?  Take your favorite conditionally convergent series ($\sum (-1)^n\frac 1n$ say).  As this can be rearranged to get any desired real number, there must be at least as many rearrangements (i.e. permutations) as there are real numbers.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am asking the first one but I am also interested in clear explanation of the second one.

Comment: You've been given links to the first. For the second, map $x\in\Bbb R$ to a permutation $\sigma$ such that using $\sigma$ to rearrange the series makes it converge to $x$. This map is certainly injective.

Comment: @lulu Please convert your comments into an answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, once you know that any conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to yield any desired real number, we immediately get an injection of $\mathbb R$ into the permutations on $\mathbb N$. To be somewhat explicit about it, pick a conditionally convergent series, such as $\sum (-1)^n\frac 1n$.   Then, given $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ we choose a permutation of that sequence which converges to $\alpha$.

Technical note:  as the above suggests, there are some issues concerning the Axiom of Choice here.  More discussion of this point can be found, e.g., [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27785/cardinality-of-the-permutations-of-an-infinite-set)

Comment: I was going to mention that this needed AC - decided not to mention that when I realized it doesn't! Given $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and our conditionally convergent series there's an explicit construction of a rearrangement that converges to $\alpha$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  True.  Though I think you need AC if you want to prove that the permutations are bijective with $2^{\mathbb N}$.  Mind you, I'm not sure I've got that right.